# Reference .properties file in classpath

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath

I want to know how to reference a .properties file in classpath? I have a jar file (contain a webservice in java), I have insert my connection details in a .properties file. I want to put this file outside the jar file in case the connection details needs to be changed. How do i reference this .properties file in my jar?

I will run my jar file using batch file.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add the ***staticresources*** directory in your buildpath, but upon doing so it shouldn't be difficult for you to implement something like

```
properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("somefile.properties"));
```

to reference your .properties file. 

I would recommend looking over  [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html)  from the Java docs for more information on accessing resources if this is unfamiliar territory.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a directory to the classpath using `java -cp /path/to/file` in your java call in your batch file.

When your properties file is in your classpath, you should be able to access it using something like:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("connectionDetails.properties");
prop.load(is);
```